# Bootstrap перекрывает мои стили

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование, bootstrap

В своем коде я подключаю навбар. Когда наводишь на ссылки, они должны быть красными, но если я подключаю бутстрап, то этого не происходит.

```
@include('layouts.inc.navbar')
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('frontend/css/bootstrap.min.css')}}">



 <div class="menu-toggle">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
</div>
<nav>
    <ul>

        <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="/about-us">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="/services">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="/contact-us">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>


 nav ul li a:hover {
    background: #f00;
 }
```

Comment: можно сделать background: #f00 !important;

Comment: Я вроде бы пытался, но оно не работало

Comment: + задайте клас ссылке например menu-link, а то это ужасно nav ul li a:hover, вот завтра я добавлю обертку и оно все полетит к чертям собачим)

Comment: Разве что-то изменит, если я задам класс?

Comment: GGO верные вещи говорит. Не подхватывается цвет, скорей всего, из-за того, что бутстрап имеет на всё свои стили, а значит перебивает кастомные. Чтобы добиться необходимого эффекта, нужна повысить специфичность. Добавить класс к необходимому тегу и уже от него отталкиваться, самый оптимальный путь. Вы спросили вопрос, мы пытаемся помочь. А вопросы изменит это что-то или не изменит выглядят странно, попробуйте и посмотрите. Мы же тоже не смотря в инспект пытаемся понять, что у вас происходит. В общем удачи.

Comment: Это не помогло.

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос был решен добавлением 3 файла с перемещением кода страницы сервиса. Сначала подключалась страница,а только потом сам навбар.

```
@include('layouts.inc.services1')
@include('layouts.inc.navbar')
```